# Python3 - Modifying Read-Only property - Not throwing AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a Java developer and learning Python. I am using Python 3.10.2.  I am trying to understand the read only variables in Python (Similar to final variable in Java), but I am bit confused about the way Python handles things. For example, below is my code.

```
class Plant:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.__name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name


table_rose = Plant("Table Rose")
print(f"Name of the plant - {table_rose.name}")

#trying to change the name.. Expecting Attribute error in the below line.
table_rose.__name = "Croutons"

print(f"Name of the plant - {table_rose.name}")  #name didnt change..

print(f"Name of the plant - {table_rose.__name}") #It prinits Croutons.. Confusing how python handling things.
```

The above code prints all three print functions like below, but I was expecting `AttributeError`

My code output

```
Name of the plant - Table Rose
Name of the plant - Table Rose
Name of the plant - Croutons
```

Can anyone explain why I didnt get any error?

Comment: That's because you've *created* the attribute `table_rose.__name`

Comment: When you use `self.__name` inside the class, it mangles it to `self._Plant__name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, Python doesn't really *do* read-only variables like Java does. So when looking at Python code when you might expect a Java class to have a private field, don't be surprised when everything is just an open variable and not wrapped up in a `property` decorator.

Anyways, onto your code :)

The cause for your confusion is something called [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables). When you're inside a class and create an attribute that starts with two underscores (e.g. `self.__name`), as a feature to allow you to avoid nameclashes when subclassing, Python inserts the class' name in front (making it actually `self._Plant__name` under the hood).

But when outside your code, and you reference `table_rose.__name`, Python doesn't do the automatic name mangling (as you're outside the class), so it references just the plain `.__name` attribute, completely missing the one that you want (called `._Plant__name`).

You can see this by using the `dir()` function. If you pass `dir` an object, it will return a list of all of that object's attributes.

```py
>>> dir(table_rose)
['_Plant__name', ... , '__name', ...]
```

This means that you're creating a brand new `.__name` variable with the value `'Croutons'`, rather than changing the existing one.

Comment: I got it.  So, we can create variables specific to an instance in Python. Am I correct?  `table_rose.new_variable = "xy"` still a valid statement correct.  So multiple instances of the same class can have their own set of variables.  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes. A Python object's attributes are fully modifiable at runtime. I can definitely see how this is weird coming from Java. Its not too inaccurate to consider each object as just a dictionary of identifiers to values, with identifier strings as keys (e.g. `'__name'`) and then other values as the value (e.g. `'Croutons'`), meaning that you are very unrestricted with object manipulation.

Comment: @user2731629 Oh, I forgot to mention, but that when declaring 'private variables' in Python, you should 9/10 use a *single* underscore rather than double (e.g. `_name`)